# There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name reg. - [unknown location]

Tags: jsp, struts2

What type of errror in my code? [This is my Project Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTYMx.png)
Any Jar File issue?or a code issue?
Any Jar File issue?or a code issue?
Any Jar File issue?or a code issue?

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:form action="reg" method="post">
            <s:textfield name="firstname" label="FirstName"/>
            <s:textfield name="lastname" label="LastName"/>
            <s:submit value="submit"/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StrutsAnnotation</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>  
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>  
                org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter  
        </filter-class>  

  </filter>  
  <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

User.java

```
package com.entity;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;



import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@Results({
       @Result(name="success", location="/welcome.jsp"),
       @Result(name="input", location="/index.jsp")
    })

public class User extends ActionSupport {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    @Action(value="reg")
    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }


}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome
</body>
</html>
```

please help me this code what is error is in this code??

Comment: Can you update the libraries, so at least have one version of framework?

Answer (score 0):

In **user.java** file change

```
@Action(value="reg")
public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

to

```
@Action(value="/reg")
public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And still not work then please check your filter class in **web.xml** based on the used struts jars.